# TFS 2012: Merging parent with all children branches at once

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, alm

I am involved in some TFS setup at my new job and one of my tasks is to setup the location of the common framework assemblies in TFS so that the other projects can reference them. The only way I can think of is to branch the assemblies from the framework folder into all of the other projects.  The issue with this is that anytime I want to update all of the projects with the new assemblies I need to merge each branch one at a time.  Is there not a way to merge all at once?

I mentioned that we should use NuGet but that would rely on the developer doing a get on the new version, they want to push it to the project to ensure that it is being used...

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: If you need to push the new version to developers, it will be also an option to you the TFS API. Depending on the trigger you could use an event web service (checkin can trigger it) or create a tool to run manually. Using the API you could get all direct branches related to your "publish" folder and do a merge to them one after each other. This way all branches will be updated and new branches will be included too.

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines as well.  Was just hoping they was an easier way like powershell script or something at least where I could recursively update all the child branches.

Answer (score 1):

NuGet is the right way to do it. Make your Framework build publish your NuGet package to a local NuGet Server from where is it is referenced by everyone. This way, when you upgrade framework, everyone will get it and you don't have to push it.

Comment: Yeah... That's what I said but they really want to push it.  The other reason they want this is because they would like to have all builds run after they new framework libs are in all of the common folders to ensure nothing has been broken.

Comment: You can use Chain builds for that 

http://blog.stangroome.com/2011/09/06/queue-another-team-build-when-one-team-build-succeeds/

My experience with using framework assemblies with reference added to all solution adds a lot of interdependencies between solutions. If one solution will fail because of some other reason, it has an impact on all others.

Comment: Thanks for the article.  It's actually not too bad though... It's just all of our web apps dependent on our common web framework library.  So it's not like I have App B that is dependent on A and C that is dependent on B and so on.  It's App B and C are dependent on A.

Comment: Ok, so Nuget might be an overkill then. Have a read through a blogpost, I wrote on the same topic about structuring your visual studio solutions 

http://hamidshahid.blogspot.com/2013/10/structuring-visual-studio-solutions-and.html

Comment: Thank you for the blog post Hamid!

Answer (score 0):

After doing lots of looking around I believe the answer to the problem is here in these two articles:

http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2009/03/05/implementing-dependency-replication-with-tfs-team-build.aspx

http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2010/12/08/dependency-replication-with-tfs-2010-build.aspx

I'll need to adapt some of the ideas within to TFS 2012.

Comment: Doing this by build sounds a bit strange to me, but if it works and is ok for you, why not. If you want to automate this, you could use Continuous Integration as trigger, so every time something was checked in in the defined workspace, the build will run ;)

Comment: Ok, but how would I ensure that the assemblies are merged into the other branches if not after a successful build?

Comment: This is most defiantly not the way to do this. You should look at Nugent. Package your core assemblies, publish them, then take the dependency using Nugent Package Manager...